# Download low resolution Image with Glide

Tags: android, android-glide

I'm doing a carousel of images and I'd like to know if with Glide I can download an image with a lower resolution. Then when the user clicks on the image (which will be smaller) and the image will appear large. I do not mean to make a thumbnail.

Answer (score 0):

No, Glide, or any other image manager can downscale an image to a lower res without downloading the whole file. You may need some server implementation to do that, like redirecting the downloaded image to your server, downscaling it and sending it to your client.